# Singular values of product of matrices with permutation matrix

Tags: random-matrices, singular-values, permutation-matrices

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and let $P \in \mathcal{P}_n$ where $\mathcal{P}_n$ is the set of all permutation matrices of size $n \times n$.
Let us define $C = AB$ and $D = APB$.

What can be said about the singular values of $D$ with respect to the singular values of $C$ ?

Thank you,

Comment: which measure are you using on permutations? The uniform one?

Comment: Yes, I can consider the uniform measure on the permutations

Comment: Sorry, I am puzzled. The sum of all permutation matrices is a scalar multiple of the matrix with ones in every entry, this has rank 1. Take $A=B$ the identity matrix, then the eigenvalues cannot be all the same.

Comment: maybe I am confused by the notation $\lambda$, what does it denote?

Comment: The notation $\lambda$ denotes the set of eigenvalues. You are right when $A = B$ the identity matrix, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: My conjecture still hold for large $n$, it seems. I updated the question.

Comment: Maybe, but feel free to decide whether to do it or not, could you share with us your numerical experiments or at least the results of them?
I am still puzzled, because if you take $A=B=I$ it seems not to work even with the limit; for any fixed $n$, since $\sum_{P\in\mathcal P_n}P=(n-1)!S$ where $S$ is the matrix with all entries equal to 1, we have $\mathbb E\lambda(P)=\frac 1{n}\lambda(S)=\{1,0,0,...\}$, identically in $n$. On the right side of the identity instead you have $\{1,1,...\}$. Maybe it is only for the ``largest'' eigenvalue that this identity holds?

Comment: You are right ! it doesn't work for the eigenvalues but I think (from numerical experiments) that it works for the singular values. In this case, your example with $A = B = I$ also works.

Comment: $A,B$ are matrices of size $n$, how do you make them depend on $n$?

Comment: You right, this doesn't make sense. I have trouble formulating the conjecture. I going to simplify the question and remove the conjecture. Thank you for your help !